# Sourcing a script not found, after checking that it exists, how is this possible?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm running a script, and this fails.

```
pwd
ls -l '.env.sh'
[ -f '.env.sh' ] && . '.env.sh'
```

I get,

```
/home/user/projects/projname
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 149 Feb 19 11:20 .env.sh
./scripts/venv.sh: 12: .: .env.sh: not found
```

How is this even possible? If the file isn't present, it never executes. I only put the `pwd` and `ls` to demonstrate that the file exists.  So the shell finds the file, and then fails to find it immediately after.

Somehow this works.

```
[ -f '.env.sh' ] && . "$PWD/.env.sh"
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Are you running the script with `bash` or `sh`? `sh` looks for the file only in `$PATH`, `bash` will also look in the current directory if not found in `$PATH`.

Comment: @Barmar : my bash version doesn't ... see my answer.

Comment: My bash on MacOS looks in the current directory regardless of posix mode, despite what the documentation says.

Comment: But on my Linux server running bash 5.x, it does what the manual says. If I run it as `bash` it finds the file, if I run it as `sh` it doesn't.

Comment: Hmmm ... so depending on system ( my OS: Linux Mint 21.2 Xfce ) bash behaves differently? Strange ... It confirms that it is necessary to look up the manual of the own version ... but I don't like to look up manuals ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of `source` or `.` command is **similar to executing a command** in POSIX mode. The `source` or `.` command will find the script from the PATH environment variable if the filename of the script doesn't contain a slash `/`.

This is the reason that you can find the script in the current directory, but `source` or `.` command couldn't find it. Because the current directory doesn't exist in the PATH env.

So, `. '.env.sh'` works only if `PATH` env contains the current directory.

Use `. './.env.sh'` or `. '$PWD/.env.sh'`

Comment: That is what I had to do, but . '.env.sh' did work when not executed in a script.

Comment: @J.M.Becker Because the current shell you are using is not in POSIX mode, which is the default. If you run `bash --posix` to start a posix shell, then `source '.env.sh'` shouldn't work.

Comment: When you put this command `source '.env.sh'` in a script and the script somehow runs in POSIX mode, then you encounter this problem.

Answer (score 2):

> What is happening here?

Just like:

```
[ -f 'ls' ] && ls
```

The path passed to `.` is searched in `PATH`. If you want to source a file from the current working directory (or any other directory), there has to be `/` in the file path. Use:

```
[ -f '.env.sh' ] && . ./.env.sh
```

Comment: By default, bash will look in the current directory if the file isn't found in `$PATH`.

Comment: Note that a 'dotted' file only needs to be readable; it does not need the execute bit set.  It does need to be on `$PATH` in general — it will be searched for using `$PATH`, at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

> *What is happening here?*

You will run again and again into similar issues you had just run into, if you don't give up on the idea that if you know how one command or executable behaves you can use this knowledge and apply it in case of running another command/executable.

Let's go to the detail:

The `ls` command is an executable file which has nothing to do with the executable running the shell (let's assume dash as a shell to stay fully within the POSIX standard) you use from within the Terminal or while running scripts.

If you pass a file name without specifying its full path the `ls` executable will look for the file in the current directory. In your case the file is there, so `ls` can list it.

Now you expect from the shell executable (dash) to do the same in order to run the file listed by `ls`. But the shell executable does not behave like the `ls` executable.
If given a file name without path specification the shell looks after the file in all the directories specified in the $PATH environment shell variable. And it will not find it there, because the file is in the current directory the shell does not check for existence of the file assuming that if you want to run an executable file which is in the current directory you will precede the file name with `./` to specify its path where the shell needs to look for the file.

Run the following script and see yourself:

```
printf pwd > local_pwd.sh
chmod +x local_pwd.sh
echo "  RUN:    local_pwd.sh :"
local_pwd.sh
echo " .RUN:    ./local_pwd.sh"
./local_pwd.sh
echo "ls -l local_pwd.sh"
ls -l local_pwd.sh
echo "END"
```

and you will see the difference in behavior between the `ls` executable and the shell.

While it is very often true that if you have understood how things work using one command or executable you can infer from this knowledge how another command or executable will behave, *but* ... there will be always cases where it will not be that way. Being aware of that will help you to check the details in the help files provided with an executable or command before you get stuck with not understanding why what worked before does not work anymore.

SUPPLEMENT (thanks to *Barmar* for the comment pointing it out):

Please *NOTICE* that the behavior of different shells (bash, dash, zsh, etc. ) can be different. Even within versions of the same shell executable you can find differences in the behavior. The behavior of the shell can also depend on some general options set in some initialization files what makes it even more confusing.
In other words, the world of computing isn't perfect ... be prepared to face it and to put the effort to read the entire manual for each new executable you start to use.

To address *Barmar's* comment

> The Bash manual says "When Bash is not in POSIX mode, it searches the current directory if filename is not found in $PATH." This is the default, so their expected behavior should work. –
> Barmar

below the full script with a log from the shell session I had run it:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

uname -a
echo "  \$BASH_VERSION: $BASH_VERSION:"

printf pwd > local_pwd.sh
chmod +x local_pwd.sh

echo "  RUN:    local_pwd.sh :"
local_pwd.sh
echo " .RUN:    ./local_pwd.sh"
./local_pwd.sh
echo "ls -l local_pwd.sh"
ls -l local_pwd.sh
echo "END"
# ---
<<shellSessionLOG_oOosys
o@s:~/oOo/O@@/stackoverflow$ pwd.sh
pwd.sh: command not found
o@s:~/oOo/O@@/stackoverflow$ ./pwd.sh
Linux s 5.15.0-76-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 15 19:16:32 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    $BASH_VERSION: 5.1.16(1)-release:
  RUN:  local_pwd.sh :
./pwd.sh: line 10: local_pwd.sh: command not found
 .RUN:  ./local_pwd.sh
/home/o/oOo/O@@/stackoverflow
ls -l local_pwd.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 o o 3 Feb 21 02:05 local_pwd.sh
shellSessionLOG_oOosys
```

Comment: The [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-_002e) says "When Bash is not in POSIX mode, it searches the current directory if filename is not found in $PATH." This is the default, so their expected behavior should work.

Comment: Yes ... this is the reason why I encourage in my answer to check out the manuals ... each kind of shell is another executable and can behave differently. There is no general rule you can apply to all the shells. So yes ... the behavior will depend on the shell you are running ... I see ... I need to mention it explicit in my answer to make it clear. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The question is tagged `bash` so you can reasonably assume that's the shell they're using. Maybe they've tagged incorrectly -- I asked above in a comment.

Comment: @Barmar: I have tested the code provided in my answer and bash does not find the file. I am not aware of changing anything about the general configuration of bash ...

Comment: To check the bash version you are using, you should run `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: @Philippe : I have incorporated the hint into my answer. Thanks.